# Unit testing different class hierarchies

Tags: oop, unit-testing, testing, tdd

What would be the best approach to make unit tests that consider different class hierarchies, like:

I have a base class `Car` and another base class `Animal`.

Car have the derived classes `VolksWagen` and `Ford`.
Animal have the derived classes `Dog` and `Cat`.

How would you develop test that decide at run-time what kind of object are you going to use.
What is the best approach to implement these kind of tests without using code replication, considering that these tests will be applied for milions of objects 
from different hierarchies ?

This was an interview question asked to a friend of mine.

Comment: Is the idea to test the base interface for the derived classes?  For example, if `Car` has a `startEngine()` and an `engineIsOn()` method, make sure that `engineIsOn()` returns `true` after `startEngine()` is called, no matter what derived class of `Car` is actually used.

Comment: Show an example of what you want to test. I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean you have *millions* of different classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem as I see it: Avoid repeating common tests to validate n derivations of a common base type.

- Create an abstract test fixture. Here you write the tests against the base type & in a abstract base class (search term 'abstract test fixture') with a abstract method GetTestSubject(). Derivations of this type override the method to return an instance of the type to be tested. So you'd need to write N subtypes with a single overridden method but your tests would be written once.
- Some unit testing frameworks like NUnit support 'parameterized tests' (search term) - where you have to implement a method/property which would return all the objects that the tests need to be run against. It would then run one/all tests against each such object at run time. This way you don't need to write N derivations - just one method.

Comment: So, your first answer is something like that ?
http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2004/05/18/134151.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that I've used before (well, a variant of this).

Let's assume that you have some sort of common method (`go`) on Car that you want to test for all classes, and some specific method (`breakDown`) that has different behavior in the subclass, thus:

```
public class Car {
    protected String engineNoise = null;

    public void go() {
        engineNoise = "vroom";
    }

    public void breakDown() {
        engineNoise = null;
    }

    public String getEngineNoise() {
        return engineNoise;
    }
}

public class Volkswagen extends Car {
    public void breakDown() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then you could define a test as follows:

```
public abstract class CarTest<T extends Car> {
    T car;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        car = createCar();
    }

    @Test
    public void testVroom() {
        car.go();
        assertThat( car.getEngineNoise(), is( "vroom" ) );
    }

    @Test
    public void testBreakDown() {
        car.breakDown();
        assertThat( car.getEngineNoise(), is( null ) );
    }

    protected abstract T createCar();
}
```

Now, since `Volkswagen` needs to do something different in the `testBreakDown` method -- and may possibly have other methods that need testing -- then you could use the following `VolkswagenTest`.

```
public class VolkswagenTest extends CarTest<Volkswagen> {
    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testBreakdown() {
        car.breakDown();
    }

    protected Volkswagen createCar() {
        return new Volkswagen();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually **Unit Test** refers to **Method Test**, when you want to write a unit test you must think to the functionality of a method that you want to write and test, and then create class(es) and method(s) for testing that. by considering this approach when you design and write your code, maybe create hierarchies of classes or just single class or any type of other designs.

but when you have to use existing design like something you mentioned above, then the best practice is to use `Interfaces` or `Base Classes` for dependecy objects, because in this way you can mock or stub those classes easily.